# Migrate native Xamarin Android app to .Net MAUI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-6.0, maui

I have a Native Xamarin Android app which is running in Target SDK 30(Android 11). I would like to migrate it into .Net MAUI. I am looking for the steps to do that.

Unable to find a documentation related to that.

Comment: You need to read the MAUI docs and learn how to write MAUI apps.  There is no magical checklist to guide you from an Android app to a MAUI app.

Comment: Since Xamarin.Android is very different from .NET MAUI, you'll have to rewrite large parts of your app, especially the UI. You won't find any guides or documentation on how to do that, because they're just too different. Migrating from Xamarin.Forms to MAUI is far easier and still poses a challenge for many apps.

Comment: To clarify: Maui is a **cross-platform** UI, so uses a different "user interaction paradigm" than Android (or any of the other platforms). Because of this, "porting" to Maui is like porting to any different platform: there are no shortcuts. Its a new implementation of your app. Its still C# and .Net, but its different APIs for user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two links for your reference.

The article is about [Migrating Xamarin.Android Applications to.NET 6](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/wiki/Migrating-Xamarin.Android-Applications-to-.NET-6). And this about [Migrating from Xamarin.Android to.NET 7](https://github.com/gmck/NavigationGraph6). It contains two Word docx files NavigationGraph.docx which describes the project and Converting a Xamarin.Android to.Net7.docx describes how to go about the detailed manual migration.

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you want to migrate to Maui? Your tags on your post don't indicate any other platform other than Android. If you only want to support Android then I can't think of any reason why you would consider Maui.

Please disregard if that is not the case.